# How to make an angular js function to change button content more than one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

html :

```
<p>
   <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#"ng-click="splendido()">{{salute}}</a></p>
```

main.js

```
$scope.splendido=function()
    {
      var calls=1;

      $scope.salute='I'm greeting you for first time';

      if(calls==2)$scope.salute="2nd time";
      if(calls==3)$scope.salute="3rd time";
      if(calls>3)$scope.salute="you're annoying me" ;
      calls++;
    }
```

the button everytime that is clicked it calls the splendido() function,**my goal would be to change the content of the {{salute}} more than one time**.
I don't manage to get it right,why it isn't updating as I expected?

I'm using Angular js 1.5.8

Comment: you can define `$scope.calls=0`.  In the function, 
`//increment 
$scope.calls=$scope.calls+1.
//then the if statements.`

Comment: The calls variable sould be defined outside the splendido function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to instantiate the variable 'salute' outside of the function, to get a default value when the controller is loaded.

Second, as in the first step, you need to initialize the 'calls' variable outside of the function, if you don't do this, 'call' always return 1.

This code works!

```
$scope.salute="I'm greeting you for first time";
var calls=1;
$scope.splendido = function() {
    if(calls==1)$scope.salute="2nd time";
    if(calls==2)$scope.salute="3rd time";
    if(calls>2)$scope.salute="you're annoying me" ;
    calls++;
}
```

Comment: you're right : I was losing myself in code for a little thing...Thank your for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Because you reset the calls variable everytime you call the function

```
$scope.splendido=function()
    {
      var calls=1; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM

      ...
    }
```

Change it to something like this:

```
var calls = 1;
$scope.salute = "I'm greeting you for first time";

$scope.splendido = function() {         
      if (calls == 2) {
          $scope.salute = "2nd time";
      }
      else if (calls == 3) {
          $scope.salute = "3rd time";
      }
      else {
          $scope.salute = "you're annoying me";
      }

      calls++;
    }
```

Comment: isn't necessary to expose the calls variable to $scope

Comment: yes you're right. just noticed after posting.. I change it.